# Generating two different random number simultaneously in Scala - Spark

Tags: scala, random, apache-spark

Can anybody help me generate two different random numbers in two ranges?  I've tried:

```
 var a = Random.nextInt(S)
 var b = Random.nextInt(K)
 if (a == S || b == K){
     a = S-1
     b = K-1
 }
 (word,a,b)
```

But this generates some numbers that are not in the specified ranges.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt(int). Returns a int value between 0 (inclusive) and the specified value (exclusive), so `a` can't be equal `S`.

Comment: but in a 1000 iteration loop it may be generate wrong , i want a complex random number generator

Comment: "it may be generated wrong", what do you mean by that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [docs on `Random`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.4/index.html#scala.util.Random$):

> `def nextInt(n: Int): Int`
>   Returns a pseudorandom, uniformly distributed int value between 0 (inclusive) and the specified value (exclusive), drawn from this random number generator's sequence.

By the method contract, `nextInt` will always return a value from 0 to `n - 1`, so your condition `a == S || b == K` will always be false.